# Authentication Error with Paypal Sandbox and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm having trouble getting the Paypal Adaptive Payments API to work with GAE - I'm specifically going to be using Implicit Payments.

The error returned is that my api credentials are incorrect, but from what i've read I should be suspicious of the header format as well.

Here's the snippet of code - I'm using the urlfetch module in GAE:

```
headers = {
        "X-PAYPAL-USERID"               : "xxxx_123456789_biz_api1.xxxx.com",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD"    : "1234567890",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE"   : "Ahg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT"  : "JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" : "JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"       : "APP-80W284485P519543T"
    }

request_body = {
        "actionType"                        : "PAY",
        "senderEmail"                       : "xxxx_123456789_biz_api1@xxxx.com",
        "receiverList.receiver(0).email"    : "xxxx_123456789_per@xxxx.com",
        "receiverList.receiver(0).amount"   : 100.00,
        "currencyCode"                      : "USD",
        "cancelUrl"                         : "some_url.com",
        "returnUrl"                         : "some_url.com",
        "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage"     : "en_US"

    }

url = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay"

result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,payload=request_body,headers=headers)
```

I've Xed out some values, but everything I'm using is coming from the sandbox "API Credentials" section.

Is there a problem with the header format? Am I using the wrong set of credentials? Can I even use the sandbox to test Implicit Payments?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

For any of those having similar problems, follow the *excellent* tutorial located here:
[Awesome Paypal Adaptive Payments Tutorial](http://blog.widenhome.com/2012/01/27/paypal-adaptive-payments-api-integration-a-step-by-step-tutorial/)
The headers do tend to cause authentication errors if not formed correctly. I was pretty far off :)

Answer (score 1):

go to your headers, and make a change like this

the key

> 'X-PAYPAL-USERID'

should become

> 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID'.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the POST method inside the `urlfetch.fetch` call; without it, [the payload data is ignored](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py).

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, 
                        payload=request_body, 
                        method=urlfetch.POST, 
                        headers=headers)
```

The `urllib2.Request` used in the Tutorial instead [switches automatically](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) from GET to POST when the request data is set.

```
req = urllib2.Request(self.request_url,paypal_request_data,header_data)
```